# checking if a random value exists from previous loop

Tags: python, loops, random

I'm trying to generate a random value for each loop and save it to variable `minimum` WHILE doing a check if that number has already been generated  before in one of the previous loops.

`listQ` basically contains **6 lines** that were randomly chosen from a file. The lines were chosen from  between `1` to `max_line` (which is basically 6 steps less than `max_line` value). So it's important that I have to generate a number that's a multiplier of 6.

```
for x in range(0, 10):
    minimum = random.randrange(0, max_line,6)
    maximum = minimum+6
    listQ = listQ[minimum:maximum]
```

A bit stuck here. A list maybe?

Comment: Sure, appending to a list and checking with ```number in list``` is possible. For large amounts of data a ```set()``` would be better though. And of course this auxiliary data-structure is defined outside of the loop!

Comment: Your logic is wrong. It doesn't make sense to assume `maximum = minimum + 6` as randrange can return 0 as a minimum value so maximum becomes just 6 at most.

Comment: Nothing wrong with 0 and 6, because 0 iz the first value from the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep a list of all the previous values and check each subsequent iteration.

```
# sets have faster "val in set?" checks than lists
# do this once, somewhere in your program
previous_vals = set()

# other stuff here, including main program loop
for x in range(0, 10):
    # find a unique, new random number while 
    # limiting number of tries to prevent infinite looping
    number_of_tries = 0
    MAX_TRIES = 10
    generating_random = true
    while generating_random:    
        minimum = random.randrange(0, max_line,6)
        if minimum not in previous_vals:
            previous_vals.add(minimum)
            generating_random = false
        number_of_tries += 1
        if number_of_tries == MAX_TRIES:
            raise RunTimeError("Maximum number of random tries reached!")

    maximum = minimum+6
    listQ = listQ[minimum:maximum]
```

Note that [there are other functions for `set` than add](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.add) if you want to modify your example.

I added a maximum number of tries too in order to prevent your code from getting stuck in an infinite loop, since I don't know anything about your input data to know what the likilhood of getting into this situation is.

Comment: Thank you, this was really helpful!

Comment: by the way is it possible to structure this so the file opens only once? is it even possible with `with open`

-----

`if reply[0] == 'm':
        with open('questions.txt') as f:
            max_line = len(f.readlines())
        with open('questions.txt') as f:
            allQ = [line.strip() for line in f]`